# XPages EL: adding a condition to select field name

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am using a sample database from the book "Mastering XPages - Second Editon" (chap11e2b.nsf), where they created an extended rich text editor.  There is a managed bean that is used to get/set the field value.  In the sample, the custom control is using this as

```
<mxpd2:inputRichText id="inputRichTextExtended"
            style="width:100%" htmlFilter="identity"
            htmlFilterIn="identity" disableModifiedFlag="false"
            htmlConversionWarning="noWarning">

            <mxpd2:this.value><![CDATA[#{rteBean['pageDocument.Body']}]]></mxpd2:this.value>
...
```

I need to check a field so I know which field to use in the control, the standard "Body" field or the "BodyHTMLMime" in case the document has a flag (field called "converted") set to "1".

How can that be done in EL language, or how can I use the rteBean.['pageDocument.Body']  in SSJS?

Worst case I create two controls and hid eacocrding to the flag, but I'm sure that is not necessary a sit can be done at the data property level.

Thanks  :)

EDIT:

My code is now this:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="BodyFieldName">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://sessionScope.BodyFieldName = 'pageDocument.Body';
viewScope.BodyFieldName = pageDocument.getItemValueString("v2_convertedtomime") == "1" ? "pageDocument.BodyHTMLMime" : "pageDocument.Body";
viewScope.BodyFieldName;        }]]>
    </xp:this.value>
</xp:text>

<mxpd2:inputRichText id="inputRichTextExtended"
    style="width:100%" htmlFilter="identity" htmlFilterIn="identity"
    disableModifiedFlag="false" htmlConversionWarning="noWarning"
    value="#{rteBean[viewScope.BodyFieldName]}">

    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:converter
            converterId="InputRichTextConverter">
        </xp:converter>
    </xp:this.converter>

    ...
```

Here is the error I get with this code:

```
1/28/16 1:45 PM: Exception Thrown
Context Path: /dev/x_docCLQC.nsf
Page Name: /page.xsp
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:865)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.invokeOnComponent(UIDataPanelBase.java:416)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.invokeOnComponent(UIDataPanelBase.java:416)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.invokeOnComponent(UIDataPanelBase.java:416)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.invokeOnComponent(UIDataPanelBase.java:416)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.layout.UIVarPublisherBase.invokeOnComponent(UIVarPublisherBase.java:155)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.invokeOnComponent(UIDataPanelBase.java:416)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.invokeOnComponent(UIDataPanelBase.java:416)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.invokeOnComponent(UIDataPanelBase.java:416)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.invokeOnComponent(UIViewRootEx.java:1552)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.AjaxUtilEx.renderAjaxPartialLifecycle(AjaxUtilEx.java:188)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.renderAjaxPartial(FacesServletEx.java:249)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceAjaxPartialView(FacesServletEx.java:200)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceAjaxPartialViewSync(FacesServletEx.java:176)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:155)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1111)
    at mxpd2.component.InputRichText.getObjectBinding(InputRichText.java:53)
    at mxpd2.component.InputRichText.processAjaxRequest(InputRichText.java:99)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.AjaxUtilEx$1.invokeContextCallback(AjaxUtilEx.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:862)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inputRichText's value has to be EL because it uses the getter and setter of rteBean.

Calculate field name and put it into a viewScope variable.

Use the viewScope variable for field name in EL:

```xml
<xp:text
    escape="true"
    id="computedField1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        viewScope.fieldName = document1.getItemValueString("converted") == "1" ? "document1.BodyHTMLMime" : "document1.Body1"; 
        ""}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
<xp:div themeId="container" style="width:800px">
    <mxpd2:inputRichText id="inputRichText1"
        value="#{rteBean[viewScope.fieldName]}">
```

Comment: And if you want to "hide", use `loaded` property rather than `rendered`, if possible.

Comment: I edited my question with the error I get when I modified the code to what you suggested.  I am totally new to EL so I am un sure what is going on...

Comment: remove the `'`s from `"'pageDocument.Body'"`

Comment: Knut, that was some testing I was doing...   I get the same error without the '    I updated the code...

Comment: from the Java code of the bean: BEAN_NAME = "rteBean".   It works if I hard code the field name, but as soon as I use the view scope variable, it gives the error

Comment: Knut, I just saw what you meant with the Bean name...  I used rte and not rteBean...    :/

Comment: OK, now I have the real code in there, using the proper bean name and no extra '.  Still get the same error.  The computed field seems to return the proper value on screen... Works great if I put the value as  "#{rteBean['pageDocument.Body']}" instead of the viewScope thing...   Guess will have two controls for today as this needs to work for tomorrow...

Comment: It does work perfect for me. I changed the code in my answer back to the version which works for original chap11e2b.nsf Xpage extendedRTE. Just try it there and make your changes then.